# $SU(5)$ model and flipped $SU(5)$ model

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory, group-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

It seems that both $SU(5)$ model and flipped $SU(5)$ model are legal grand unified theories (GUT) for the standard model gauge group. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipped_SU(5)), it says that:

> The flipped $SU(5)$ model has a gauge group breaking down
> $$(SU(5) × U(1)_ χ )/ Z_5 \to (SU(3) × SU(2) × U(1)_Y )/ Z_6  $$
> The flipped $SU(5)$ model representation branchings (very different from $SU(5)$ model):
> $$\bar{5}_{-3}\to (\bar{3},1)_{-\frac{2}{3}}\oplus (1,2)_{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ ($u_c$ and $l$)
> $$10_{1}\to (3,2)_{\frac{1}{6}}\oplus (\bar{3},1)_{\frac{1}{3}}\oplus (1,1)_0$$ ($q$, $d_c$ and $ν_c$)
> $1_{5}\to (1,1)_1$ ($e_c$)

My question is that:

- do we still have the $B-L$ or $5(B-L)-2Y$ global symmetry for the flipped $SU(5)$ model?
- Does the proton decay still happens in the flipped $SU(5)$ model?
- What are the pros and cons of $SU(5)$ model versus flipped $SU(5)$ model?